# porque algunos comandos no muestran la salida?

Tags: python, socket

Estoy haciendo un servidor y cliente. Todo va bien, pero en la shell cuando tengo el cliente.py ejecutando y al insertar algunos comandos como `rm -r`, `shred -u`... se ejecuta correctamente en la shell del otro computador, pero en la terminal mia del cliente se queda como si no se hubiese ejecutado, es decir, así:

```
1.0.0.0@nombre_pc:$shred -u texto
|
```

mientras que en comandos como `ls` imprime una salida:

```
$ls
Descargas
Documentos
Escritorio
Imágenes
Música
Plantillas
Público
snap
Videos
1.0.0.0@nombre_pc:$
```

servidor.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#Se importa el módulo
import socket, os, getpass, shutil, shlex, commands
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
name_host_server = getpass.getuser()
carpeta_actual_server = os.getcwd()
#instanciamos un objeto para trabajar con el socket
ser = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = ""
port = 8000
#Puerto y servidor que debe escuchar
ser.bind((server, port))
#Aceptamos conexiones entrantes con el metodo listen. Por parámetro las 
conexiones simutáneas.
ser.listen(1)

#Instanciamos un objeto cli (socket cliente) para recibir datos
cli, addr = ser.accept()
while True:
#Recibimos el mensaje, con el metodo recv recibimos datos. Por parametro la cantidad de bytes para recibir
recibido = cli.recv(1024)
cd_recibido = recibido.count("cd")
text_recibido = recibido.count("-t") 
ventana_error_recibido = recibido.count("-m --error") #ok
ventana_info_recibido = recibido.count("-m --info") #ok
ventana_input_recibido = recibido.count("-m --input") #ok
ventana_question_recibido = recibido.count("-m --question") #ok
ventana_warning_recibido = recibido.count("-m --alert") #ok
ventana_notification_recibido = recibido.count("-m --notification") #ok
if text_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-t ","")
    print(texto_filtro)
    cli.send(texto_filtro)
elif cd_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("cd ","")
    os.chdir(texto_filtro)
    cli.send(texto_filtro)
elif ventana_input_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-m --input ","")
    comando = shlex.split("zenity --entry --title '' --text %s --display :0" % texto_filtro);
    proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    salida = proceso.stdout.read()
    cli.send(salida)
elif ventana_error_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-m --error ","")
    comando = shlex.split("zenity --error --title '' --text %s --display :0" % texto_filtro);
    proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    salida = proceso.stdout.read()
    cli.send(salida)
elif ventana_info_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-m --info ","")
    comando = shlex.split("zenity --info --title '' --text %s --display :0" % texto_filtro);
    proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    salida = proceso.stdout.read()
    cli.send(salida)
elif ventana_notification_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-m --notification ","")
    comando = shlex.split("zenity --notification --title '' --text %s --display :0" % texto_filtro);
    proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    salida = proceso.stdout.read()
    cli.send(salida)
elif ventana_warning_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-m --alert ","")
    comando = shlex.split("zenity --warning --text %s --display :0" % texto_filtro);
    proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    salida = proceso.stdout.read()
    cli.send(salida)
elif ventana_question_recibido == 1:
    texto_filtro = recibido.replace("-m --question ","")
    comando = shlex.split("zenity --question --title '' --text %s --display :0" % texto_filtro);
    proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    salida = proceso.stdout.read()
    cli.send(salida)
else:
    salida = commands.getoutput(recibido)
    cli.send(salida)           
if ser == True:
    print("Conexion cerrada")
#Cerramos la instancia del socket cliente y servidor
cli.close()
ser.close()
```

El problema debe de venir de aquí:

```
    else:
       salida = commands.getoutput(recibido)
       cli.send(salida)
```

Pero no se que cual es el error

Cliente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding_utf-8 -*-
#Variables
import socket, os
host = "1.0.0.0"
port = 8000
obj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
obj.setblocking(0)
obj.connect((host, port))
name_host_server = socket.gethostname()
print("[+] conexion establecida")
while True:
   mens = raw_input("\033[1;31m"+host+"\033[1;32m"+"@"+name_host_server+":"+"\033[0;37m"+"$ ")
   if mens == "close":
      os.system("fuser -k -n tcp %s" % port)
      break
      #Con el metodo send, enviamos el mensaje
   obj.send(mens)
   data = obj.recv(1024)
   print(data)
   #Cerramos la instancia del objeto servidor
obj.close()

#Imprimimos la palabra Adios para cuando se cierre la conexion
print("Conexion cerrada")
```

Comment: Particularmente el comando `shred -u archivo` no tiene ninguna salida, puedes probar con la opción `verbose` con `shred -u -v archivo`

Comment: Si, pero es normal que se quede como congelado, sin acabar la ejecución?

Comment: Habría que ver como tienes el cliente, si estas esperando si o si recibir algo, puede ser que el cliente sea el que quede bloqueado. Prueba en caso de no tener `salida` retornar un mensaje cualquiera tipo `Comado ejecutado`.

Comment: En el cliente tengo el `data = obj.recv(1024)` y lo imprimo, teóricamente me tendría que ir bien ya que el data esta esperando a recibir la salida de los comandos ejecutados en el servidor, y los comandos como `ls` `ifconfig`,etc imprime una salida.

Comment: Una posibilidad es que tengas los `sockets` en modo `blocking` (que es el modo por defecto) lo que significa que se quedará esperando recibir los datos, sin datos `recv()` quedará a la espera de los datos por siempre ya que los comandos no retornan nada. Prueba setear antes que nada en el cliente el modo no bloqueante con `obj.setblocking(0)`

Comment: Me da un error `sh: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected. codigo actualizado en cliente.py.

Comment: `sh: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected`, hay un error de sintaxis, pareciera por algún `;` no esperado, lo que no puedo saber es si esto es el retorno que recibes o un error en la ejecución del cliente.